# H2 Database timestamp insert null

Tags: database, h2

Good Day,

I need to clear a timestamp on my H2 Database. I can set values but I can't set it to null/clear it!

What is the command?

```
UPDATE TABLE SET DATE='null' WHERE USERNAME='User'
```

doesnt work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'null'` is a string with the text *null*, it's not the *value* `NULL`.

You need to remove the single quotes:

```
UPDATE the_table 
   SET DATE = null 
WHERE USERNAME='User'
```